# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm pretty new with ASP.NET Core Razor Pages and I would like your help on the following.

I have the following two classes:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a name.")]
    [Display(Name ="Customer Name")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer Email")]
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Display(Name ="Customer Phone Number")]
    public string CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; } = new();
}
```

and

```cs
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Invoice Number")]
    public string InvNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Amount")]
    public decimal InvAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Issued? (Yes/No)")]
    public bool InvIssued { get; set; } = false;
    [Display(Name = "Paid? (Yes/No)")]
    public bool InvPaid { get; set; } = false;

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The way I've set it up is for a one-to-many relationship. Now, two related issues are that during the `Create` form for an invoice I also need to input a `CustomerId`, otherwise I get an SQL exception error. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to bind the data, to the Customer table, so that I can retrieve the list of available customers and have it as an option during the creation of an invoice.

My `.cshtml` file contains:

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="form-control" value="3"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Invoice.InvNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Invoice.InvNumber" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Invoice.InvNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Invoice.InvNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Invoice.InvAmount" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Invoice.InvAmount" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Invoice.InvAmount" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
 
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="InvIssued" id="InvIssued" value="true" checked="">
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="Invoice.InvIssued">
                The invoice has been issued.
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="InvNotIssed" id="InvNotIssed" value="false">
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="Invoice.InvIssued">
                The invoice has not been issued.
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and my page model is:

```
public class AddInvoiceModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly InvoicesAppContext InvoiceContext;

    public AddInvoiceModel(InvoicesAppContext contextInvoices)
    {
        InvoiceContext = contextInvoices;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }


    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

       InvoiceContext.Invoice.Add(Invoice);
       await InvoiceContext.SaveChangesAsync();

       return RedirectToPage("../Index");
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

- How do I add a reference to Customer table in the `AddInvoice` Page Model?
- The `CustomerId` is an `int` and not the actual name of the customer. How do I retrieve the names and not the id?

Thank you all for your help. And sorry for this basic stuff. I am still learning.

Comment: What's your result of ModelState.IsValid ?

Comment: If I use `input asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="form-control" value="3"/>` to hard wire the value 3 then the ModelState.IsValid = true. Otherwise (i.e., if I do not have the value 3) I get the SQL exception.

Comment: "I retrieve the names and not the id" where do you want to retrieve the names ?

Comment: Hi Qinq. The user should see the name of the Customer in a drop list (or something) rather than just a number (int id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when creating an invoice, you know who the customer is, and therefore their ID. You assign this to the Invoice in `OnGet`:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    Invoice = new Invoice{ CustomerId = id };
    return Page();
}
```

It's then a question of adding that ID to the invoice form so that it is posted along with the rest of the invoice details. You'd add it to the form as a hidden field:

```
<input asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" type="hidden" />
```

If you don't know who the customer is, you provide a select list containing customers so that the user can select one for the invoice. You bind the select element to the `Invoice.CustomerId` property:

```
<select asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" asp-items="Model.CustomerOptions"></select>
```

The `CustomerOptions` is a `SelectList` that you populate in the `OnGet` handler:

```
public SelectList CustomerOptions { get; set; }
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    CustomerOptions = new SelectList(await db.Customers.Select(x => new SelectListItem{
        Value = x.CustomerId.ToString(),
        Text = x.CustomerName
    }).ToListAsync(), nameof(SelectListItem.Value), nameof(SelectListItem.Text));
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you for this. Are you aware of any additional resources I can use? I am having some issues with just using your code :)  For example, in the first method I get the "The name "id" does not exist in this context". In the second method the `public SelectList CustomerOptions { get; set; }` gives an error (doesn't recognise SelectList).

Comment: I recommend some time learning the basics to be honest. You can try the official documentation, or my site (which marsan has linked to) or, ahem, my book. Google my name. You should find a link to it.

Comment: Your book is in the mail :D

Answer (score 0):

In the AddInvoiceModel:

```
 public class AddInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {
       private readonly InvoicesAppContext InvoiceContext;

       public AddInvoiceModel(InvoicesAppContext contextInvoices)
         {
           InvoiceContext = contextInvoices;
         }

        public SelectList CustomerOptions { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            List<Customer> cities = new()
            {
                new Customer { Id = 1, CustomerName = "Latur" },
                new Customer { Id = 2, CustomerName = "Solapur" },
               
            };// you also can get data from database
            CustomerOptions = new SelectList(cities.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.CustomerName
            }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
            return Page();
        }
```

In cshtml file:

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
           <select asp-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.CustomerOptions"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Invoice.CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

result:

[image]